# Openbr - system runtime library file does not exist: msvcp120.dll

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, biometrics, openbr

I just found out about Openbr and started to install required libraries like OpenCV and QT. I followed these instructions for windows(win10 64bit):
http://openbiometrics.org/docs/install/#windows
but unfortionatly got stuck when executing the following command:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

with this output:

```
CMake Error at C:/opencv-2.4.11/build-msvc2013/win-install/OpenCVConfig.cmake:71 (include):
include could not find load file:

C:/opencv-2.4.11/build-msvc2013/win-install/OpenCVModules.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:87 (find_package)


-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/classification
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/cluster
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/cmake
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/core
-- importing C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/cuda/module.cmake
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/distance
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/format
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/gallery
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/gui
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/imgproc
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/io
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/metadata
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/output
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/representation
-- adding C:/openbr/openbr/plugins/video
CMake Error at openbr/CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    C:/openbr/openbr/janus

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules    /InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake:463 (message):
  system runtime library file does not exist:
  'MSVC12_REDIST_DIR-NOTFOUND/x64/Microsoft.VC120.CRT/msvcp120.dll'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  share/openbr/cmake/InstallDependencies.cmake:135 (include)
  openbr/CMakeLists.txt:67 (install_compiler_libraries)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake:463 (message):
  system runtime library file does not exist:
  'MSVC12_REDIST_DIR-NOTFOUND/x64/Microsoft.VC120.CRT/msvcr120.dll'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  share/openbr/cmake/InstallDependencies.cmake:135 (include)
  openbr/CMakeLists.txt:67 (install_compiler_libraries)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/openbr/build-msvc2013/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: install visual c++ runtime libraries for visual studio 2013: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: I have already installed and the output is the same